# FluentValidation Registration

Tags: servicestack, fluentvalidation

ServiceStack version: 3.9.43

I am using the built-in IoC container and the built-in FluentValidation. I register my validators using a reference to the assembly where they are:

```
Plugins.Add(new ValidationFeature());
container.RegisterValidators(typeof(Foo).Assembly);
```

Based on the [IoC docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#object-lifetime) I expect that my validators are instantiated only once. Unfortunately it looks like their lifetime is request scoped and I get a fresh set created with each request, which is expensive.

Given that the validators are [thread safe](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/discussions/77488) is there a reason why `RegisterValidators` behaves the way it does? If not, what would be the recommended way to register my validators as Singletons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just committed an overload to RegisterValidators that allows you to [specify the scope of which the FluentValidation validators are registered in](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/92e96d2e60406c5c6c4f8e5022fff73c5b07bad3). You can now specify a singleton scope with:

```
container.RegisterValidators(ReuseScope.Hierarchy, typeof(Foo).Assembly);
```

Note: You would only want to do this if your validators don't make use of disposable resources, e.g. db, datastore/network connections.

Available on NuGet in next release of ServiceStack v3.9.53+.

Comment: 1) looking at releasing a new version either tonight or tomorrow, usually releases are fortnightly if tests pass and happen on the weekend (so you can calculate new release date based on the last). 2) the previous commit was a few mins old, before I decided it wasn't a good idea to have a singleton default, so I made it overridable instead.

Comment: on a release - getting a release today/tomorrow would be great ... on usage - gotcha.